# How to connect php to navicat with 2 tables

Tags: php

```
$i = 1;
$sql = "
    SELECT
        heroes.char_id, characters.char_name, heroes.class_id, heroes.count, 
        heroes.played, heroes.active FROM heroes, characters
    WHERE characters.obj_Id = heroes.char_id AND heroes.played = 1
    ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td><span id='lefttop'><b><font color='#007aa2'>".$i++."&nbsp;</font></td><td><b><font color='#f6ff00'>".$row['char_name']."</font></td></span><div style='float:right;'><td><b>&nbsp;".$row['count']."</td></div> <br />
    </tr>
    ";
}

echo "";
?>
```

Anyone can help? im trying to make a hero status script on a java server, and i need to connect into 2 tables which is "heroes"(this is where i get the hero) and "character" (this is where i get the hero names)

Comment: Navicat is just a database administration tool. Which database system are you using? How do the tables look like? Have you connected to the database in your PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Temple:

```
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * your table1";
$query1 = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo "<tr>";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * your table2";
    $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {

        echo "<td>[yor Vars here]</td>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```